# How can I do a COMMIT without first doing an initial checkout?

Tags: svn, commit, svn-checkout

I have a repository already online, but I want to commit what I have on my hard drive and disregard what is on the online repository.

I know I can do an initial checkout on a blank folder, then delete the downloaded files, paste the new files to the folder in Windows Explorer and **then** do a commit. But I'd rather skip this step. There must be a way to do this. Right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can delete files directly in the repository in [**TortoiseSVN**](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/)'s "browse repository" dialog.
There, you can also add files from your local drive directly using "Add..." or doing a simple drag and drop.